# Segmentation fault when accessing returned pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a data structure that contains the data size and the data itself and I also have two functions that serialize a de-serialize that same structure.

Note that these serialize functions are not totally practical or effective.

My `data_t` structure:

```
struct data_t {
    int datasize; 
    void *data; 
};
```

My function `data_To_buffer` that converts the structure to a buffer:

```
int data_to_buffer(struct data_t *data, char **data_buf) {
    if (data == NULL || data_buf == NULL)
        return -1;

    int buf_size = INT_S + data -> datasize;

    *data_buf = malloc(buf_size);
    char *buf_ptr = *data_buf;


    int int_v = htonl(data -> datasize);
    memcpy(buf_ptr, &int_v, INT_S);
    buf_ptr += INT_S;

    memcpy(buf_ptr, data -> data, data -> datasize);

    return buf_size;
}
```

My function `buffer_to_data` that converts a buffer to a data_t object.

```
struct data_t *buffer_to_data(char *data_buf, int data_buf_size) {
    if(data_buf == NULL || data_buf_size <= 0)
        return NULL;

    int size = ntohl(* (int *) data_buf);
    data_buf += INT_S;

    struct data_t *data = data_create(size);


    memcpy(data -> data, data_buf, data -> datasize);

    printf("\n SIZE: %d", data -> datasize); <- OK = 14
    printf("\n Data: %s\n", data -> data); <- OK = 1234567890abc
    return data;
}
```

**The problem**

At my `main` when I test these functions there is an error when I try to print the value of the de-serialized data.

Note that when I print the `data` and `datasize` in the `buffer_to_data` function there is no problem at all, only after I return the data the error occurs.

```
int main() {
int data_size;
    struct data_t *data, *data2;
    char *data_s = strdup("1234567890abc");
    char *data_buf;
    data_size = strlen(data_s)+1;

    data = data_create2(data_size, data_s); <- OK

    int buf_size = data_to_buffer(data, &data_buf); <- OK

    data2 = buffer_to_data(data_buf, buf_size);

    printf("\n DATA2 SIZE: %d", data2 -> datasize); <- SEGMENTATION FAULT 
    printf("\n DATA2 Data: %s\n", data2 -> data);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve]?  This should be a complete program that someone could compile and run verbatim, without having to guess how to fill in the missing parts.  In particular, include the code of `data_create2` so we can see how the data object is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```c
memcpy(buf_ptr, &int_v, INT_S);
```

You missing dereference to the inner buffer, instead you overriding passed pointer

Fixed line:

```c
memcpy(*buf_ptr, &int_v, INT_S);
```

Same error here:

```c
buf_ptr += INT_S;
memcpy(buf_ptr, data -> data, data -> datasize);
```

Fixed variant:

```c
memcpy(*buf_ptr + INT_S, data -> data, data -> datasize);
```

Comment: Does not work, Core dumped right on the first change.